# Anyone knows of way to compare your mobile with a 'standard' installation set?

Tags: applications

I have a **Samsung Galaxy S** mobile phone, running **Android 2.1**, and am very pleased with it (can't compare though, since it's my first device with Android).

When I had some problem with the installed Facebook application, and got some answers here fro the site, it seemed that I was using a 'Facebook S!' application and not the 'standard' Facebook for Android.

I was just wondering just now: **is there a way to compare an Android on your device with a standard installation ?** I , for one , would like know that applications have been written by my mobile manufacturor and my mobile operator, and which are standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an absolute answer, but if you go into Settings, Applications, Manage Applications. Then press Menu, select Filter, and make sure that Third-party is selected. Anything in that list didn't get onto your phone as part of the standard Android install. They've either been added by your phone manufacturer, your phone network, or yourself.

Unfortunately some standard Android apps show up in that list, if you've updated them from the market (like Google Maps) and a lot of manufacturer added apps don't show up.

I've got a Galaxy S too, but had a HTC Magic running stock Android before. Apps that I've spotted as obviously being modified/added by Samsung are the Music Player app, Camera app, Contacts App, Clock app, Daily Briefing, FM Radio, Video PlayerMemo, Mini Diary, My Files, Samsung Apps (and everything listed in there), Social hub, Voice Recorder, Task Manager. Also a lot of the "Look and feel" of the phone, including the way the 7 home screens, and the Applications screens work has been added as part of Samsung's Touch Wiz interface.

TL;DR Galaxy S has a lot of custom apps, easiest way to compare is probably actually to find someone with a stock phone (like a Nexus One) and directly compare.